# Running spring boot app after teamcity build and deploy

Tags: java, spring-boot, teamcity, devops

Is there another way to run deployed spring boot application on server than *sh script? 
My idea is create .sh script which will start app (java -jar name...). This solution is simple but have one disadvantage - I have application version in the file name. I can trust that there will be only one *jar file and run it - but I am not sure that it is best solution.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `maven-assembly-plugin` to bundle your application jar and sh script onto one zip file. In this case you could use maven resource filtering to put replace `${version}` placeholder in your sh with exact version of your jar during maven build.

If your jar has name like this: `my-project-.jar1 then your sh script will look like this:

```
java -jar my-project-${version}.jar
```

During build maven will replace `${version}` with value from pom.xml.
So after build you need to unpack zip (or tar.gz) and execute sh script.